# Prove that the measure of central angle is equal to the measure of its intercepted arc.

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, solid-geometry, plane-geometry

> **Give the proof that the measure of central angle is equal to the
>   measure of its intercepted arc.**

Any suggestions and help are greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: OK, but then the radius is $1$.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. The [definition of the *radian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) is: "*The length of an arc of a unit circle is numerically equal to the measurement in radians of the angle that it subtends*". If you use a different definition for "***the measure of central angle***" then you should spell that out in the the question itself.